# facing errors while installing laravel by composer in wamp

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I want to install laravel through composer in WAMP environment. I got the following errors:

```
   Failed to download laravel/laravel from dist: You must enable the openssl e
tension to download files via https


[RuntimeException]
 Failed to clone https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git, git was not found,
 check that it is installed and in your PATH env.
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
program or batch file.
```

Comment: download project via `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel some_name`

Comment: Is openssl (PHP extension) enabled?